# AngularJS drag drop in a table cell

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-sortable, ng-grid

I just started learning AngularJS and its really been a nice ride until now.
I am trying to implement a drag drop feature on the table cell.

I tried with all existing directives on drag drop but i couldn't figure it on the table cells.

I am assuming multiple directives are involved in here (eg: sortable for rows, drag drop directive)?
Do i need to create a new directive which does all the functions or can i use all the directives on top a table.

Can some one please throw some light on it?

Comment: Is it possible to use the ngGrid Table, have a cell Template and in the html have the drag drop ability?

Comment: Please find the plnkr for it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmB2HnS5bgNhNXALxAUq

I am trying to drag items from list below, into the table column (State). I am using ngGrid for the table. I have cell Template for the State column.

Also i there no call back functions is triggered once the item is dropped.

Not sure if i am doing the right thing?